# How to control visibility of a PCF using Reflection in Guidewire

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I am trying to use `<Reflect>` on my PCF RangeCell element ( ClaimCenter version -10) to control the visibility of this field. Is that possible at all?

What I have now is below: it doesn't work...

```
   <RangeCell
      editable="UI.Status.editable(document)"
      id="Status"
      label="&quot;Status&quot;"
      required="UI.Status.required(document)"
      value="document.Status_ext"
      valueRange="UI.Status.filter(Status_ext.getTypeKeys(false), document) as java.util.List&lt;Status_ext&gt;"
      valueType="typekey.Status_ext"
      valueVisible="UI.Status.visible(document)">
      <Reflect
        triggerIds="SomeType"
        valueRange="UI.Status.filter(Status_ext.getTypeKeys(false), document) as java.util.List&lt;Status_ext&gt;">
      </Reflect>
    </RangeCell>
```

Also tried adding `<ReflectCondition>` which didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visible property in pcf with the approprite conditions. Another way to write a boolean function in the enhancement class and call this function to the 'available' property. Not sure about reflection.

Hope, it helps.